# How to solve this cardinality word problem?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, pigeonhole-principle

Jack and Jill are playing a game. A natural number $m$ is fixed at the start
of the game (say, by rolling a die or using a random number generator).
Game play goes as follows:

- Jack picks a natural number $x$ no bigger 
  than $2m$.
- Jill picks $x$ numbers between $1$ and $2m$.
  Jack wins if Jill picks at least one even number.

Otherwise, Jill wins.

What is the smallest number Jack should pick in order to guarantee a win?
Prove your claim.

---

How do I reason through this?

Comment: is 'between' inclusive or exclusive?

Comment: Inclusive I am assuming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many odd numbers are there?  Jack needs Jill to pick more than that.

Comment: Yes, but how do I formally write that out?

Comment: @Shuri2060:  I think it is a big enough hint to be an answer.

Comment: I'm confused by your hint to be honest @RossMillikan

Comment: @sgerbhctim:  "Jill can pick at most ___ odd numbers, so if she is asked to choose more than that, at least one must be even."

Comment: @sgerbhctim [Pigeonhole Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)

Comment: Meaning it is $m+1$?

Comment: Assuming between $1$ and $2m$ allows $1$, yes

Comment: Does this make sense? Assuming between $1$ and $2m$ is inclusive, Jill can pick at most $m$ odd numbers. Therefore, if she is asked to choose more than that, meaning $m+1$, at least one number must be even. By the Pigeonhole Principle, the smallest number that Jill can pick, in order for Jack to have a gauranteed win is $x=2m+1$.

Comment: Yes, that is fine.  Please stay to the same terms-we were using $m$ not $n$ and it was Jack and Jill playing the game.

Comment: I'm worried that this does not **prove** my claim though..

Comment: Yes, it does.  You have shown that $m+1$ is enough and you have shown that $m$ is not enough because Jill can pick that many odd numbers.